# How to compile LuaFileSystem library and get .dll file WITHOUT luarocks?

Tags: c, dll, lua, luafilesystem

So, I got file "lfs.c" "lfs.h" "lfs.def" and ".gitignore". I tried installing MinGW and typing in that command: `gcc lfs.c` (Keep in mind that I'm a total newbie in such things), which leaves me with error "failed to include lua.h"... I don't know how to do that, can anyone please explain to me how to do that? Or at least give me the link to already compiled lfs.dll?

Comment: Compiling is more than just calling `gcc`. Check if LFS contains a `configure` script, and if it does, run it, then run `make`. Also, you need to add the headers and libraries for Lua to the appropriate places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely to be missing Lua include files; see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26164943/1442917) for details on how to set it up.

Simply getting lfs.dll may not be so easy as different DLLs may depends on different Lua DLLs on Windows. I have lfs.dll that is compiled against Lua51.dll, so if this works for your project/needs, you can [get a compiled version here](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/blob/master/bin/clibs/lfs.dll).