# Add lua binaries to MinGW

Tags: lua, mingw

I have downloaded the lua binaries "lua-5.3.2_Win32_dllw4_lib" for MinGW, but i dont know where in the mingw folder to extract them. Does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT: Sorry not binaries, I ment DLL and includes.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a dll/include *for* MinGW as it's a DLL/library compiled using MinGW. You need to make them available in your project directory and reference those files when you compile libraries/modules that need to reference Lua header files or libraries. See for example this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163903/building-luafilesystem-for-lua-for-windows/26164943#26164943) on how this is done for luafilesystem module.