# Windows: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'lua.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, windows, lua, lupa

I have tried to some requirements for a python project in windows, using pip install -r requirements.txt, however this keeps failing. After some investigation I have found that it fails because of lupa.
Running "pip install lupa" shows the same error as for when I try to install the requirements as shown in the stacktrace below:

```
Collecting lupa
  Using cached lupa-1.2.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: lupa
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lupa: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lupa: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command d:\development\tools\python\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Achiraaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-g477k1jp\\lupa\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Achiraaz\AppData\Local\Temp\tmped2hn2icpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  No local build of LuaJIT2 found in lupa directory
  Checking for installed luajit library using pkg-config
  pkg-config found luajit version 2.0.4

  building without Cython
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lupa
  copying lupa\version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lupa
  copying lupa\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lupa
  running build_ext
  building 'lupa._lupa' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.5
  creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\lupa
  D:\Development\IDE\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DLUA_COMPAT_ALL -I/usr/include/luajit-2.0 -Id:\development\tools\python\include -Id:\development\tools\python\include "-ID:\Development\IDE\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-ID:\Development\IDE\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\winrt" "-ID:\Development\IDE\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-ID:\Development\IDE\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\winrt" /Tclupa/_lupa.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5\Release\lupa/_lupa.obj
  _lupa.c
  lupa/_lupa.c(265): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'lua.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'D:\\Development\\IDE\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for lupa
Failed to build lupa
Installing collected packages: lupa
  Running setup.py install for lupa: started
    Running setup.py install for lupa: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command d:\development\tools\python\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Achiraaz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-g477k1jp\\lupa\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Achiraaz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-5d7gkihi-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    No local build of LuaJIT2 found in lupa directory
    Checking for installed luajit library using pkg-config
    pkg-config found luajit version 2.0.4

    building without Cython
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lupa
    copying lupa\version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lupa
    copying lupa\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lupa
    running build_ext
    building 'lupa._lupa' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\lupa
    D:\Development\IDE\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DLUA_COMPAT_ALL -I/usr/include/luajit-2.0 -Id:\development\tools\python\include -Id:\development\tools\python\include "-ID:\Development\IDE\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-ID:\Development\IDE\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\winrt" "-ID:\Development\IDE\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-ID:\Development\IDE\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\winrt" /Tclupa/_lupa.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5\Release\lupa/_lupa.obj
    _lupa.c
    lupa/_lupa.c(265): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'lua.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'D:\\Development\\IDE\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
```

I tried at first to compile and install luajit, using the approach described on: http://luajit.org/install.html but this didnt solve the problem.

Then I managed to install luajit (at least I think I did) using hererocks, but for some reason it wont pick up lua.h even though the file is in the luajit/include library, so the end result was the same.

I found this article: [Building luafilesystem for Lua for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163903/building-luafilesystem-for-lua-for-windows)
and I tried to play around with the environment variables described but no luck..

It seems to me like the file is for some reason not included in the build and I cannot make it resolve this.

All or any help and suggestions are appreciated.

I am running windows 10 with visual studio express edition. I have cygwin and mingw installed but I'd like to stick with the SDK if possible.

Comment: I would love to see an answer for this!

Comment: Could not reproduce on Python 3.9.2 lupa 1.9, ´pip install lupa´ inside a ´virtualenv´ (and outside) without issues.